# Why is the p (paragraph) tag removed when all text is removed from the field?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, ckeditor5

I have multiple "CKEditor" editors on the same page. And now I observe strange behavior.

For example, I am initializing CKEditor to the `p` tag. And this works:

[image]

That is, I delete the text, but the first `p` tag of this kind is always kept:

```html
<p data-placeholder="Type some text...">...</p>
```

But the [documentation](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/integration/basic-api.html) always contains this example:

```html
<div id="editor"></div>
```

I change the `p` tag to `div` and I get this:

[image]

Above, when deleting text, this code is removed:

```html
<p data-placeholder="Type some text...">...</p>
```

But if remove the focus from the field, then the tag `p` appears again:

[image]

Has anyone encountered similar behavior?

Comment: Fancy animations, reminds me of the old gif era. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Vue. And I used `v-html` to render the original values. That was the problem. I fixed the problem using the `setData` method from CKEditor.